# While loop not progressing when list entry is not present in text file search

Tags: python

I was hoping someone may be able to shed some light on my loop issue.  Apologies for the long explanation!

Basically I have a script which collects various stats, but also collects 'frame' numbers and puts them into 'framelist[ ]' from a huge text file, once the frame numbers are collected the script continues by perfroming a new search on the same text file to search for these frame numbers and extracts some more useful information.  It's a bit overly complicated but I had to do it this way as the second search collects some new stats based on the first search from strings further down the text file.  Meanwhile I am posting the collected stats to Excel using xlsxwriter and doing the usual row+=1 to add stats.  So far it works, however it gets even more complicated.

Next what I do is convert the framelist into 'ints' and deduct 1 from all framelist entries, I then convert back into a new list of strings 'framelist1[ ]' with the new entries (with '1' subtracted).  I do this to find the previous frame number.  Then I run another search to collect similar stats info from the previous frame number.  All ok so far.... until a 'subtracted' frame number is not found. If the new 'subtracted' frame is not present in the text file the python scipt hangs.  What I am keen to do is to ignore a missing frame if it is not present in the text file and just put a 'Null' or 'Skip' entry in the Excel file.  I have played around with various try: and except: functions, but still with no luck, the script still hangs.  I have posted my while loop below when it is processing framelist1[ ].  I have left both 'Skip' and 'Null' attempts in the code, to show what I have tried so far.  Apologies for the complicted methods, I am still learning Python, and I know there is a beter way of doing this by avoiding multiple searches, but doing it this way I know whereabouts I am in the script when it goes wrong!

here's the loop...

```
        framelist = map(int, framelist)
        framelist[:] = [x - 1 for x in framelist]

        framelist1 = map(lambda x: str(x), framelist)
        framelist = []
        #framelist1 = ''(str(e) for e in framelist)

        num = 0

        while num < len(framelist1):
            for i, line in enumerate(searchlinesBMA):
                try:
                    word = framelist1[num]
                    print word
                    if word in line:
                        keylineBMA = searchlinesBMA[i-2]
                        Rline = searchlinesBMA[i+10]
                        Rline = re.sub('[()]', '', Rline)
                        valueR = Rline.split()
                        split = keylineBMA.split()
                        try:
                            if split[10] == 'A':
                                worksheetFILTERA.write(row_numBMAA1,4,valueR[3], decimal_format)
                                row_numBMAA1+=1
                                num+=1
                        except:
                            worksheetFILTERA.write(row_numBMAA1,4,'SKIP')
                            row_numBMAA1+=1
                            num+=1
                            break
                    elif word != framelist1[num]:
                        worksheetFILTERA.write(row_numBMAA1,4,'NULL')
                        row_numBMAA1+=1
                        num+=1
                        break
                except:
                    pass
```

Thanks,
MikG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not incrementing `num` on the `except` statement at the bottom of your example. So if it errors on the start of the `try` block you have yourself an infinite loop.

You are not incrementing `num` if there isn't anything in `searchlinesBMA`.

```
while num < len(framelist1):
    # if searchlinesBMA is empty here you dont increment `num`
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlinesBMA):
         #Your code..

    #increment num needed here?
    if not searchlinesBMA:
        num += 1
    else:
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlinesBMA):
            # Your code..
```

Might be worthwhile printing errors caught by the except. Might give you a better idea whats going wrong:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shadow9043.  I can see the first point you mention where I am not incrementing num on the except: path, though this still sees the script hanging. With your other suggestion how would I go about incrementing num on in searchlinesBMA, I thought this would be covered in the except: path?  Thanks, MikG

Comment: Have a look above. Just updated my answer. See if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Shadow9043